# Google maps place api - nothing found on request

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api

When i search place in Autocomplete i get 'nothing found on request' in Xamarin.Android. How to fix this?

**Inialization API**

`if (!PlacesApi.IsInitialized)
            {
                PlacesApi.Initialize(context, "MY_API_KEY");
            }`

**Call Place Autocomplete**

```
List<Place.Field> fields = new List<Place.Field>();

        fields.Add(Place.Field.Id);
        fields.Add(Place.Field.Name);
        fields.Add(Place.Field.LatLng);
        fields.Add(Place.Field.Address);

        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.Overlay, fields)
            .SetCountry("US")
            .Build(this);

        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: are you passing valid data?

Comment: Hi , you can have a look at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) to check where problem is .

Comment: Did you try http api?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=central%20park&types=address&key=Your_API_Key&origin=40.7828647,-73.9653551&location=40.7828647,-73.9653551&radius=3000

Comment: Do you have billing enabled on your project, and the Places API enabled? Is your API key properly restricted? Also what errors do you get?